# Redux normalized state tree for posts and comments

Tags: mongodb, redux

Redux recommends using normalized app state tree but I am not sure if it's the best practice in this case. Assume the following case:

1. Each `Circle` has_many `Posts`.
2. Each `Post` has_many `Comments`.

In the database on the backend, each model looks like this:

Circle:

```
{
  _id: '1'
  title: 'BoyBand'
}
```

Post:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  circle_id: '1',
  body: "Some Post"
}
```

Comment:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  post_id: '1',
  body: "Some Comment"
}
```

In the app state (the final result of all reducers) on the frontend looks like this:

```
{
  circles: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        title: 'BoyBand'
      }
    },
    allIds: [1]
  },
  posts: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        circle_id: '1',
        body: 'Some Post'
      }
    },
    allIds: [1]
  },
  comments: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        post_id: '1',
        body: 'Some Comment'
      },
    allIds: [1]
  }
}
```

Now, when I go to `CircleView`, I fetch `Circle` from the backend which returns all `posts` and `comments` associated with it.

```
export const fetchCircle = (title) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: constants.REQUEST_CIRCLE,
    data: { title: title }
  })

  request
    .get(`${API_URL}/circles/${title}`)
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return
      }

      // When you fetch circle from the API, the API returns:
      // {
      //   circle: circleObj,
      //   posts: postsArr,
      //   comments: commentsArr
      // }
      // so it's easier for the reducers to consume the data

      dispatch({
        type: constants.RECEIVE_CIRCLE,
        data: (normalize(res.body.circle, schema.circle))
      })
      dispatch({
        type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
        data: (normalize(res.body.posts, schema.arrayOfPosts))
      })
      dispatch({
        type: 'RECEIVE_COMMENTS',
        data: (normalize(res.body.comments, schema.arrayOfComments))
      })
    })
}
```

Up to this point, I think I did everything in a fairly standard way. However, when I wanted to render each `Post` component, I realized that populating the posts with their comments became inefficient (O(N^2)) compared to when I kept my state tree in the following format.

```
{
  circles: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        title: 'BoyBand'
      }
    },
    allIds: [1]
  },
  posts: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        circle_id: '1',
        body: 'Some Post'
        comments: [arrOfComments]
      }
    },
    allIds: [1]
  }
}
```

This goes against my understanding where in a redux state tree, it's better to keep everything normalized.

**Q.** Should I in fact keep things denormalized in a case like this? How do I determine what to do?

Comment: Are you worried about performance, rebuilding the tree, or what?

Comment: Can you add the code responsible of the performance bottleneck ? The component & container code maybe ?

Comment: Because there is nothing bad with your approach, you just select the comments body based on comment's id, even if it's O(n^2) where n is the number of posts o it shouldn't be too much of a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

### I'd go for: yes normalize it, but do it on the backend!

**Why?**

- **Deleting is easier**

because otherwise, you'd have to track down the posts and comments every time you'd want to delete a circle, or post.

- **Working with the data is easier**

because otherwise, you'd have to do the same mutations on your data over and over again just so that you can select the dataset which is related to a particular circle or post.

- **You don't have any many-to-many relationship**

you don't have multiple posts which link to the same comment so it just makes sense to have the data normalized.

- **You shouldn't be limited by an API**

If this is a third-party API then make your backend fetch the API and normalize the data there. You shouldn't be restricted by the API and I don't know what kind of data you access but you can definitively save a DNS lookup for the user and serve cached data if the API is unavailable. If you rely on the API to being up you introduce a single point of failure.

---

About your performance issues, they should be insignificant if you normalize on the backend and you should measure it and take the critical code for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the list of comments is specific for any post. User cannot post one comment into multiple posts. And there's nothing wrong that comments are tightly coupled with the post. It's easy to update/remove specific comment(both postId and commentId are present). Removing a post is trivial. Same with circle. It's insignificantly harder to remove all comments of a specific user. And I think that there are no strict rules, the RIGHT way, etc... more often it depends. [KiSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

While thinking how to organize comments on client side I was reading this article, it's about possible db structures for similar situation. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/